# What encryption technology does Adobe RTMFP use?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, rtmfp, soundcloud-stratus, adobe-cirrus

the only information i found online is that RTMFP uses 128-bit cypher. Does anyone know what exact encryption technology is used?

Comment: https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/Cumulus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to OpenRTMFP, it uses AES, see
 https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/Cumulus/blob/master/CumulusLib/sources/RTMFP.cpp
and https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/Cumulus/blob/master/CumulusLib/sources/AESEngine.cpp